# Windows AD picture not updating on lock screen

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

What are the steps for troubleshooting a users Active Directory picture that will not update on any terminal servers in your network? I am talking about the picture that shows up above the users name on the lock screen. Updating Active Directory does update the picture in Exchange. This is only affecting one user.

**Update 1:**

Updating users profile picture by opening a .JPG image with PHP and reading it into a buffer. Then assigning that buffer to an array with a key of thumbnailphoto and the value as the buffer from above. Then using the PHP ldap_modify command to update AD.

Comment: Can you post your method of how you uploaded the pictures, as I have seen it done a few different ways before with different outcomes.

Comment: I have updated the post with how the images are uploaded.